# Will the beaker be acted upon by the force in the direction of the green arrow?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics

[image]

The black circle is the top view of the beaker. In the gravity field, the beaker is vertical down along the beaker axis. The beaker is still. The water in the beaker rotates at a uniform angular speed in the direction of the red arrow. A force pushes the beaker to accelerate in the direction of the blue arrow. If so, is this another Magnus Effect?